# Download PDFs from Prawn File in Zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

In my WebApp, I generate bill with Prawn.

I'd like to download all bills in zipped file !

I did that :

```
def download
  bills = Bill.search(params[:q]).result(distinct: true).paginate(:page => params[:page], limit: 20, order: "paid_at DESC")

  bills.each do |b|
    Prawn::Document.generate("#{Rails.root}/public/pdfs/web_#{b.reference}.pdf")
  end


  require 'rubygems'
  require 'zip'
  zipfile_name = "#{Rails.root}/public/pdfs/factures.zip"
  Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    bills.each do |bill|
      zipfile.add("web_#{bill.reference}.pdf", "#{Rails.root}/public/pdfs/web_#{bill.reference}.pdf")
    end
  end

  path = File.join(Rails.root, "public", "pdfs")
  send_file File.join(path, "factures.zip")
end
```

But the PDFs are empty because I do not specify the "*.prawn" file that allow to generate the PDF !

Can anybody, give me the way to do that ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

My show.pdf.prawn

```
prawn_document() do |pdf|


pdf.image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.jpg"
  pdf.move_down 30

  pdf.move_down 10
  pdf.text "<b>Email :</b> <a href='mailto:contact@mtaville.fr'>contact@mtaville.fr</a>", inline_format: true
  pdf.text "<b>Site :</b> <a href='http://www.mtaville.fr'>www.mtaville.fr</a>", inline_format: true

  pdf.move_up 230
  pdf.table [["Facture N° #{@bill.reference}"],["Date : #{ldate(@bill.paid_at, format: :short2)}"]], position: :right do
    cells.style do |c|
      c.background_color = "2857BE"
      c.text_color = "FFFFFF"
      c.border_color = "2857BE"
      c.align = :center
    end
  end

  pdf.move_down 30
  pdf.table [["CLIENT"]], position: :right do
    cells.style do |c|
      c.background_color = "2857BE"
      c.text_color = "FFFFFF"
      c.border_color = "2857BE"
      c.width = 280
    end
  end

  pdf.bounding_box([260, 600], :width => 280, :height => 80) do
    pdf.text "#{@bill.billable.name}", style: :bold
    pdf.text "#{@bill.billable.address_1} #{@bill.billable.address_2}"
    pdf.text "#{@bill.billable.zipcode} - <b>#{@bill.billable.town}</b>", inline_format: true
  end

  pdf.move_down 100
  pdf.text "<b>Objet :</b> Facture n° #{@bill.reference}", inline_format: true

  if @bill.billable_type == 'Subscription'
    pdf.move_down 10
    data = [
      ["Produit", "Prix unitaire HT", "Prix total HT"],
      ["Renouvellement de souscription à votre espace privé", "#{number_to_currency(@bill.total)}", "#{number_to_currency @bill.total}" ]
    ]
    pdf.table data, width: 540 do
      cells.style do |c|
        c.background_color = (c.row == 0)? "2857BE" : "ffffff"
        c.text_color = (c.row == 0)? "ffffff" : "000000"
        c.font_style = (c.row == 0)? :bold : :normal
      end
    end
  end
  if @bill.billable_type == 'Order'
    pdf.move_down 10
    data = [
      ["Produit", "Prix unitaire HT", "Prix total HT"],
      ["Annonce n°#{@bill.billable.ad.id}", "#{number_to_currency(@bill.total)}", "#{number_to_currency @bill.total}" ]
    ]
    pdf.table data, width: 540 do
      cells.style do |c|
        c.background_color = (c.row == 0)? "2857BE" : "ffffff"
        c.text_color = (c.row == 0)? "ffffff" : "000000"
        c.font_style = (c.row == 0)? :bold : :normal
      end
    end
  end

  pdf.move_down 20
  data = [
    ["Total HT", "#{number_to_currency(@bill.total)}" ],
    ["Total TVA #{@bill.tva}%", "#{number_to_currency(@bill.amount_vat)}"],
    ["Total TTC", "#{number_to_currency(@bill.amount_inclusive_of_tax)}"]
  ]
  pdf.table data, position: :right do
    cells.style do |c|
      c.font_style = (c.row % 2 == 0)? :bold : :normal
      c.width = 140
      c.align = (c.column == 1)? :right : :left
    end
  end

  pdf.move_down 20
  data = [["NET A PAYER", "#{number_to_currency(0)}"]]
  pdf.table data, position: :right do
    cells.style do |c|
      c.font_style = :bold
      c.background_color = "2857BE"
      c.text_color = "ffffff"
      c.width = 140
      c.align = (c.column == 1)? :right : :left
    end
  end

end
```

** ANSWER **

Here is the fonction in my controller :

```
def download
    bills = Bill.search(params[:q]).result(distinct: true).paginate(:page => params[:page], limit: 20, order: "paid_at DESC")

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'zip'
    require 'bill'
    zipfile_name = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdfs/factures.zip"
    Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
      bills.each do |bill|
        temp_pdf = Tempfile.new("web_#{bill.reference}.pdf")
        temp_pdf.binmode
        temp_prawn_pdf = BillPdf.new(bill)
        temp_pdf.write temp_prawn_pdf.render
        temp_pdf.rewind
        zipfile.add("web_#{bill.reference}.pdf", "#{temp_pdf.path}")
        temp_pdf.close
      end
    end

    path = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", "pdfs")
    send_file File.join(path, "factures.zip")
  end
```

And my class :

```
class BillPdf < Prawn::Document
  include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  def initialize(bill)
    super()
    image "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo.jpg"

    move_down 10
    text "<b>N° TVA :</b> TVA", inline_format: true
    text "<b>Siret :</b> 789 618 691 00016", inline_format: true
    text "<b>Site :</b> <a href='http://www.mtaville.fr'>www.mtaville.fr</a>", inline_format: true

    move_up 230
    table [["Facture N° #{bill.reference}"],["Date : #{l(bill.paid_at, format: :short2)}"]], position: :right do
      cells.style do |c|
        c.background_color = "2857BE"
        c.text_color = "FFFFFF"
        c.border_color = "2857BE"
        c.align = :center
      end
    end

    move_down 30
    table [["CLIENT"]], position: :right do
      cells.style do |c|
        c.background_color = "2857BE"
        c.text_color = "FFFFFF"
        c.border_color = "2857BE"
        c.width = 280
      end
    end

    bounding_box([260, 600], :width => 280, :height => 80) do
      text "#{bill.billable.name}", style: :bold
      text "#{bill.billable.address_1} #{bill.billable.address_2}"
      text "#{bill.billable.zipcode} - <b>#{bill.billable.town}</b>", inline_format: true
    end

    move_down 100
    text "<b>Objet :</b> Facture n° #{bill.reference}", inline_format: true

    if bill.billable_type == 'Subscription'
      move_down 10
      data = [
        ["Produit", "Prix unitaire HT", "Prix total HT"],
        ["Renouvellement de souscription à votre espace privé", "#{number_to_currency(bill.total)}", "#{number_to_currency bill.total}" ]
      ]
      table data, width: 540 do
        cells.style do |c|
          c.background_color = (c.row == 0)? "2857BE" : "ffffff"
          c.text_color = (c.row == 0)? "ffffff" : "000000"
          c.font_style = (c.row == 0)? :bold : :normal
        end
      end
    end
    if bill.billable_type == 'Order'
      move_down 10
      data = [
        ["Produit", "Prix unitaire HT", "Prix total HT"],
        ["Annonce n°#{bill.billable.ad.id}", "#{number_to_currency(bill.total)}", "#{number_to_currency bill.total}" ]
      ]
      table data, width: 540 do
        cells.style do |c|
          c.background_color = (c.row == 0)? "2857BE" : "ffffff"
          c.text_color = (c.row == 0)? "ffffff" : "000000"
          c.font_style = (c.row == 0)? :bold : :normal
        end
      end
    end

    move_down 20
    data = [
      ["Total HT", "#{number_to_currency(bill.total)}" ],
      ["Total TVA #{bill.tva}%", "#{number_to_currency(bill.amount_vat)}"],
      ["Total TTC", "#{number_to_currency(bill.amount_inclusive_of_tax)}"]
    ]
    table data, position: :right do
      cells.style do |c|
        c.font_style = (c.row % 2 == 0)? :bold : :normal
        c.width = 140
        c.align = (c.column == 1)? :right : :left
      end
    end

    move_down 20
    data = [["NET A PAYER", "#{number_to_currency(0)}"]]
    table data, position: :right do
      cells.style do |c|
        c.font_style = :bold
        c.background_color = "2857BE"
        c.text_color = "ffffff"
        c.width = 140
        c.align = (c.column == 1)? :right : :left
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You could use `Tempfile` to generate a temporary file and add it to the zip. Make sure that you close the file once you're done using it.

Comment: Ok, but How can I add content in that tempfile ?

Comment: See my Answer, I've expanded on this thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment more, see the code refactor below. Instead of adding the files to your public directory, which is dangerous for security reasons, you can use `Tempfile`s. You may need to tweak this a bit, but should give you the basic idea behind `Tempfile`s.

```
def download
  bills = Bill.search(params[:q]).result(distinct: true).paginate(:page => params[:page], limit: 20, order: "paid_at DESC")

  require 'rubygems'
  require 'zip'
  zipfile_name = Tempfile.new(["#{Rails.root}/tmp/factures", '.zip'])
  Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    bills.each do |bill|
      temp_pdf = Tempfile.new(["basic_questions_#{Time.now.to_i}", '.pdf'])
      temp_pdf.binmode
      temp_prawn_pdf = Prawn::Document.new(#WHATEVER YOUR PARAMETERS ARE)
      temp_pdf.write temp_prawn_pdf.render
      temp_pdf.rewind
      zipfile.add("web_#{bill.reference}.pdf", "#{temp_pdf.path}")
      temp_pdf.close
    end
  end

  path = File.join(Rails.root, "public", "pdfs")
  send_file File.join(path, "factures.zip")
ensure
  zipfile_name.close
end
```

Comment: Since this could take a long time, you may want to move this into a `delayed_job` or similar. Whenever the file is ready, you can initiate the download or send an ajax that the files are ready to download. It really all depends on the scope of how your application is built as to what will fit in best.

Comment: I take it for the security. But, all my PDFs are blank !

Comment: In the line `temp_prawn_pdf = Prawn::Document.new(#WHATEVER YOUR PARAMETERS ARE)`, you need to set `Prawn::Document.....` to whatever is the PDF generator. For example, look in your other code where the document successfully generates and put that code there; modifying any necessary parameters.

Comment: It's a really big file ! Is there a way to reference that file ??

Comment: What is a big file, the Prawn class that is generating the file, your your code that leads up to the generating of the PDF? Can you post what you have in your question?

Comment: I would refactor that off to a helper or create a pdf class that inherits from Prawn::Document. This way, you can use something like `class BillPdf < Prawn::Document` and then reference BillPdf.new(parameters you're using) in any place where the bill pdf is being generated. Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=prawn on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I refactor my code in a class ! I update the code I do in the question !